# Find if searBar.text contains an integer string?

Tags: ios, swift, search, filter, int

I am trying to update my search results based on the number typed into the searchBar. However, it does not recognize the number when I use this code

```
switch searchBar.text! {
    case "", nil:
        inSearchMode = false
    case "\(Int)":
        filteredData = dataSource.data.filter({"\($0.genusNum!)" == self.searchBar.text! })
    default:
        inSearchMode = true
        filteredData = dataSource.data.filter({$0.identifier?.range(of: lower) != nil })
    }
```

It will work however, when I replace `Int` with an actual integer. The problem is i need it to work for any integer I type in, since the range of numbers is huge i can't make a case for each individual number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get int value like this

swift 1

```
if let intValue = searchBar.text.toInt() where intValue > 0 {
// do your stuff
}
```

swift 2 and 3

```
if let intValue = Int(searchBar.text) {

   if intValue > 0 {

   }

}
```

Hope this helps you